# Is this possible to filter https request using squid acl?

Tags: squid

I am using squid proxy 3.1. I want to allow users to  access particular domain urls only. Say allow only this url  "https://google.com/search"  through squid proxy. Default squid does not know the url because https request is encrypted. For that , I am using `ssl_bump` to decrypt the `CONNECT` requests.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

#allowing .zoho.com domains
acl trustedDomains dstdomain .google.com

#allowing grid console.
acl search urlpath_regex /search/

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
http_port 3129  ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/test.crt key=/etc/squid/test.key

# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#

# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
#http_access allow allowurls
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
cache deny trustedDomains

#filtering external domains
http_access deny !trustedDomains

ssl_bump allow trustedDomains search
ssl_bump deny all

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow CONNECT
#We recommend you to use at least the following line.
#hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320


logformat squid  %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %>A %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %un %Sh/%<A %mt
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
```

This acl is blocking all domains besides "google.com" but I can access any urls from "google.com". I am expecting to allow "/search" only.